# Pass VBA Sub a Range

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getitng this Error "Type missmatch"

I want to be able to format cells in my spreed sheet by passing a range and a value I'd like displayed.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

```
Sub Layout()

Call Create_Box("A1:A2", 10)

End Sub

Sub Create_Box(R As Range, V As String)


    Dim box As Object
    Set box = Range(R)
        With box
            .Merge
            .Value = Box_value
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Border.Style = continous
            .Border.Color = black
            .Border.Weight = xlThick
        End With

End Sub`
```

Comment: In addition to the points raised in the answers, is `Box_value` meant to be `V` in this code?

Comment: Yeah it is, I messed around with a lot of it trying to get it to work,

Answer (score 4):

The parameter you are passing in is not a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx); just a string represenfting a range object's local [Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx).

```
Sub Layout()
    with activesheet  '<-set this explicitly to something like With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Call Create_Box(.range("A1:A2"), 10)
    end with
End Sub

Sub Create_Box(R As Range, V As String)
        With R
            .Merge
            .Value = Box_value
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Border.Style = xlContinuous
            .Border.Color = 0
            .Border.Weight = xlThick
        End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
Sub Create_Box(R As String, V As String)
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass it as a range object.

```
Sub Layout()
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

    Set r1 = ws.Range("A1:A2")
    Call Create_Box(r1, "10")
End Sub

Sub Create_Box(R As Range, V As String)
Dim box As Object
Set box = Range(R.Address)
    With box
        .Merge
        .Value = Box_value
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Border.Style = continous
        .Border.Color = black
        .Border.Weight = xlThick
    End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Small note: if `R` is a Range object, you probably don't want to use `Set box = Range(R)` - unless `R` is a cell containing the name/address of another range of interest. ;)

Comment: @MatthewD why not simply use R directly, or change the R parameter to box? Or use set box = R